# Transform low AC voltage input

Tags: transformer

I have 2.2 volts low impedance AC from a constant source. If I build a transformer to input 2.2v on the primary and output 120v on the secondary can I expect to operate any household appliances, such as a 1000 watt microwave?

Comment: Not on this planet. If V21=120/2.2=55 then you need to supply  55x times more current than the load

Comment: You'd need something like a welding transformer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a 100% efficient transformer, you would need 1000W input at 2v, which is not far short of 500A.

If your low impedance source can deliver that, and if you have thick enough leads to the transformer to avoid too much voltage drop, then yes.

In practice, I doubt you can answer either of those 'ifs' with 'yes'.

Comment: For the OP: It's helpful to think of this in wattage rather than just volts/amps. To provide 1000W of output at 2.2V, you need to be supplying 1000/2.2 = ~455A. As Neil noted, this assumes 100% efficiency, in reality you might be getting 80%, which pushes your requirements up.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. What if I use the 2.2 volts to turn an induction motor? Is there a way to eventually generate  the power I need in stages by using generators and transformers?

Comment: Ah! Are you trying to get free energy? No. There is no way.

Comment: Help me to understand this Neil_UK. Forgive me if I don't ask the question right. If one can transform 120 volts to 240 volts does the power change? You say it doesn't, and this is because of the current, which has to adjust to a lower value: P=IV? Correct? My erroneous thinking comes from believing that a generator creates power, such as found at a hydroelectric source--a dam. So, it seems to me that if a generator creates power from the turbine action of water, why can't an induction motor drive a generator to create power. You know I'm missing something. What is it?

Comment: I'm thinking that it must be the potential energy of the flow of water and the conversion into electricity in the dam's generator or something like this. Thanks for any help on this. It really leaves me baffled.

Comment: @londailey Do you understand [levers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever)? If I try to lift a rock, with a long length of 2x4, the lever *creates* extra force at the expense of movement, just like a transformer *creates* extra volts at the expense of amps, or creates extra amps at the expense of volts. In both cases, the power at output and input is identical (less losses). Concentrate on the moment at the fulcrum of the lever, it doesn't *know* how long the lever is, there's just a certain amount of turning force available. Long lever, low end force. Short, large force. May update answer.

Comment: @londailey `it seems to me that if a generator creates power from the turbine action of water, why can't an induction motor drive a generator to create power.` The water, high up, has potential energy. As it falls to a lower level, it releases it. The turbine and generator convert that energy to electrical. Energy is always a product of two things, VxA, force x distance, torque x angle, and that product can never increase, though you can increase one at the expense of the other. Like cash is the product of coin value and the number of them, you can't increase your money by getting change.

Comment: Thank you Neil_UK. Great explanations. Your "Like cash is the product of coin value and the number of them, you can't increase your money by getting change." is somewhat profound even though you likely didn't intend it to be. It seems to apply to many life situations.

Comment: @londailey It was intended to be profound in the physics sense, energy is the *currency* of physics, and it's what you have to spend resources on if you're buying machinery. While a high voltage low current supply, or a high current low voltage supply can be reasonably cheap, a high power supply is expensive. It wasn't intended to be profund for other life situations, but if you take something useful from it, then great.